# How can I redirect a new bare domain to its subdomain without hurting SEO?

Tags: seo, htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect, subdomain

I want to install my new site content on a subdomain like
`subdir.example.com` instead of the root domain.

This is a new domain and it has no previous content to redirect. The root URL will be empty and inaccessible to anyone trying to browse the root site `example.com`.  It will be redirected to `subdir.example.com` automatically.

I'm not sure if there's a better SEO way to do it.
Will Google find this redirection weird and penalize the site in some way?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is here? Like you say, "This is a new domain and it has no previous content" - so where is the potential SEO issue here? "a better SEO way to do it" - do what exactly? Are you asking from a technical aspect - how to implement this in `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how you setup a www. domain. There is nothing wrong with it in terms of SEO. However, if you are creating a keyword subdomain there may be issues with that.